# PDF modify takes time in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to modify a pdf file and to add specific data into it.

Here is the scenario I have, I have a DataTable that contains thousands of rows, each row represents a customer or client, and I have one pdf template.

I have to modify the pdf template for each row (client or customer) to add their id to the file in addition to other data and then it will be added to the DataTable for that client.

I'm using this code to do the needed job, but it times out when processing huge amount of rows or it takes at least 15 mins, 4k rows in my case- because this means opening the pdf file 4k times and modifying it as needed.

```
// file is the pdf tmeplate, id is the customer's id - represens 1 row in the DataTable, landingPage: is client's specific page should be added to the file
private static byte[] GeneratePdfFromPdfFile(byte[] file, int id, string landingPage)
{

    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
            var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
            //Open the document for writing
            doc.Open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            ////parse html code to xml 
            //iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < reader.NumberOfPages + 1; pageNumber++)
            {
                doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                doc.NewPage();
                //Insert to Destination on the first page
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
                int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pageNumber);
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
            }

            // Add a new page to the pdf file
            doc.NewPage();
            // set pdf open action to open the link embedded in the file.
            string _embeddedURL = "http://" + landingPage + "/Default.aspx?code=" + id;
            PdfAction act = new PdfAction(_embeddedURL);
            writer.SetOpenAction(act);
            doc.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Note: I'm using ForEach loop to iterate through the DataTable rows

Comment: I/O operations are slow, unfortunately. I am assuming you're opening the template x amount of times that is specified in the DataTable, if so, look at opening it once and keeping it in memory, you'll shave some time off already here.

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks! but any ideas how to do that?

Comment: keep in mind, I have to close the file - or the stream - because I want to save it and then i'm converting it to byte[] to save it back to the Db

Comment: You're saving the modified files in a database? That could be the real bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, didn't see that. If you step through the code, figure out which part(s) take the most time to complete. Perhaps DB call take a lot of time to save the PDF.

Comment: @DanWilson No not each time i'm writing the file back to the Db! once i'm done generating the files then I'm using SQL Bulk to do that by one call.

Comment: You should be able to load the PDF into memory, make a copy, modify that copy and save the file.  Copy the original again, for the next record, make changes to it and save the file.  I am not sure how that is done with itext but it should be fairly simple and there should be examples on their site and or the general web.  If possible you can eliminate the saving of the PDF altogether and just send the bytes from memory directly to the database and that would also eliminate the bulk load at the end.

Comment: If you are using a database like SQL server you can also consider using file tables to store / work with the PDF's.  Amazing possibilities there, not sure if they fit your model though.

Comment: You are doing it all wrong. Please throw away your code, and start anew. You are using an old iText version that is no longer supported. If you want to stick to that old version, you need to use `PdfStamper` instead of `PdfWriter`. If you can upgrade to iText 7, please upgrade to iText 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (the text) doesn't correspond with your code (the C# part). You are asking one thing (add content to an existing PDF), and doing another thing (add an option action to an existing PDF), but regardless of what it is that you want to do, you shouldn't use `PdfWriter` to make a shallow copy of every page of an existing PDF (throwing away all interactivity).

You can significantly reduce the lines of code you wrote by using `PdfStamper`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
string _embeddedURL = "http://" + landingPage + "/Default.aspx?code=" + id;
PdfAction act = new PdfAction(_embeddedURL);
stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction(act);
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
return ms.ToArray();
```

Please read [chapter 6](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book to see why `PdfWriter` is the wrong class for you. `PdfStamper` is meant to manipulate an existing PDF document, keeping all its existing features intact.

Also be aware that you're using an old version of iText. The most recent version is [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). Please consult the [Jump-Start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version) for more info on using the latest iText version.

Comment: Thanks - I consderd updating it and replacing the code with the one you wrote.
but i ran to this exception:
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: the file's size is 370KB only and I'm generating 4150 files -or copies using your approach

Comment: I added a line that releases memory. A 370 KB file shouldn't cause an out of memory exception. Wrong use of resources in a loop can.